# Yii2 - Does this make any difference for executing query ? if yes than what

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am going to execute below query in yii2.

```
$result = MyModel::find()->where(['res_model'=>$res_model])->all();
```

What is the difference between above query and this one query :

```
$result = MyModel::find()->where( 'res_model = :res_model',[
                    ':res_model' => $res_model] )->all();
```

both working fine but bit confusing about both performance and usability.
can anyone give clarification on these please ??

Comment: I'm not experienced with Yii's ORM, but it looks like the first version you would simply pass the variable to the query whereas in the second version you would build a query with parameters, which would not bring any performance disadvantages, but would increase, in theory at least, the security of your applications. Normaly, an ORM would sanitize the binded parameters. I don't know how Yii's ORM is handling this though.

Comment: @Dragos yes , you correct that second one give better security . the second one is parameterize query and the first one is direct query.
but any performance advantage over there with second query ?? and anything else in this ??

Comment: Regardless of the answer to your question about performance, would you actually value more the performance than the security of your application?

Comment: @MiteshShah both versions are giving exactly the same security, I don't know why you think the second is safer. The first one is processed by Yii 2 to produce binded parameters just like the second one sets directly. If you care for extra nanoseconds I guess second is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Same queries will be executed.
First version is useful if you have several key=value conditions.
Second version can be used if you need to do more complex query. Something like this

```
$result = MyModel::find()->where('some_field = (select max(date) from another_table where another_field=:param)',['param' => $param])->all();
```

Perfomance and security is the same.

Answer (score 0):

For sql/mysql these are the same  (both the query shoul return the same code  )

the difference is the the way you assign the value for the filter ..

```
  $result = MyModel::find()->where(['res_model'=>$res_model])->all();
```

In the second the assign of the value is based  using param  tecnique    and not directly

```
  $result = MyModel::find()->where( 'res_model = :res_model',[
                ':res_model' => $res_model] )->all();
```

Comment: These are the same and it's **not** true you could get SQL injection by using first one.